# what type of windows device driver can modify FindFirstFile and FindNextFile?

Tags: c++, c, windows, device-driver

i need to add some files to results returned by FindFirstFile and FindNextFile under windows. Is this possible by file system filter driver or what type of drivers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by File System Filter Driver. But you can do this by implementing a system wide API hook. I have not tried it before but you really don't need to take the pains of writing the drivers and making the system unstable in case of spoiling the driver stack.

[System Wide API Hooking](http://help.madshi.net/SystemWideApiHooking.htm)

[API Hooking Revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @sarat, i prefer write device driver to use native functions, but i did not find correspondending IRP request! Can you point me?

Comment: Yes, you can do this by intercepting ntdll apis. In particular, you will need to intercept NtQueryDirectoryFile. Refer to http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/kernel32/file.c#L1728 to see how Wine implemented FindFirstFile. I believe this is quite similar to what Windows actually did.

Comment: You can probably use IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL for that. Please take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548658.aspx for more detailed info.

Comment: Another source that you can use is http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/ that is a library to hook APIs. It also has wide hooking. The best method is developing a driver because it's the only way you are sure that everything will finish there.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you can use a file system filter driver (legacy or mini-filter, based on `fltmgr`). However, I would strongly recommend *against* the system-wide API hooking. Simple reason: if you do it in usermode it's not really going to be system-wide and if you use an SSDT-hook or some hotpatching method you risk the system's stability. An alternative, albeit equally shady as system-wide hooking, would be entry-point stealing. In this case you use the device object of the volume (in which you're interested, just listen for the attach notifications or enumerate them at startup) to find the driver responsible for it and modify the major function entry points in the driver object (Ilho pointed you into the right direction already).

A file system filter driver is the *supported* method to do just that.

In the latest Windows 7 WDK the sample under `7600.16385.1\src\filesys\miniFilter\minispy` provides a good starting point. Biggest problem with mini filters for a private person is to get assigned an altitude for the driver to load at. Because using just *any* altitude can well lead to BSODs - and in case of FSFDs you might even risk your data integrity (although the kernel steps in with the BSOD to prevent that). You only need to fake `IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY` - this is the minor control code you're looking for when you are handling the `IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL` major control code. All others you can pass through as long as you don't need to allow the file to be opened, read or written and such. How to do that can be seen in the `7600.16385.1\src\filesys\miniFilter\passThrough` sample source.